# Travel pass in Brittany, France?

Tags: tickets, public-transport, france, brittany

Is there a travel pass available, with which it is possible to take any (most) train and bus in Brittany within a certain time period (e. g. for one week)?

I searched on https://www.mobibreizh.bzh/ but was not able to find anything relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [KorriGo card](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/KorriGo), which covers a fair amount of trains and buses in Brittany within a certain time period.

Some possible plans to use with the KorriGo card:

- https://www.ter.sncf.com/bretagne/abonnements/tous-les-abonnements/abonnements-ter-reseaux-urbains/abonnement-mensuel-ter-reseaux-urbains
- https://www.star.fr/titres-et-tarifs/trouver-mon-tarif
- https://www.ter.sncf.com/bretagne/services-contacts/carte-korrigo

Comment: Thanks, my French is not the best, but do I understand correctly that this card has to be topped up and then swiped upon boarding? If so, where do I find a table of fares? It would be great if you could explain in more detail how a tourist goes about getting the card, topping it up and using it.

Comment: @erc answer edited, sorry it's indeed a bit of a mess, many possible plans, subnetworks, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look into https://www.ter.sncf.com/bretagne/tarifs-cartes/pass-ter-breizhgo ?

My impression is that buses in Bretagne typically cost 2.50 Euros and are so infrequent that you are unlikely to take more than two per day.